# How to create this layout using LinearLayout?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout

I want to construct below layout using LinearLayout. 
[image]
I created that using ConstraintLayout,but it was too long for me. And now I am wondering how this layout could be created via LinearLayout? Is it possible? And also pictures have to have their own size,because I suppose that if it is match_parent or wrap_content,quality of image will be bad. This is how I tried to construct via LinearLayout,but result is too different. So,what I have to do?

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.example.abay.myeleven.MyTeamActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/attacks"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        >

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="@dimen/player_width"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/player_height"
            android:src="@drawable/player_default"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#FFF"
            />

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="@dimen/player_width"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/player_height"
            android:src="@drawable/player_default"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#FFF"
            />
        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="@dimen/player_width"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/player_height"
            android:src="@drawable/player_default"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#FFF"
            />











    </LinearLayout>



    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/midfields"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        >
        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="@dimen/player_width"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/player_height"
            android:src="@drawable/player_default"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#FFF"
            />

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="@dimen/player_width"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/player_height"
            android:src="@drawable/player_default"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#FFF"
            />
        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="@dimen/player_width"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/player_height"
            android:src="@drawable/player_default"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#FFF"
            />



        </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/defenders"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"

        >
        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="@dimen/player_width"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/player_height"
            android:src="@drawable/player_default"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#FFF"
            />

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="@dimen/player_width"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/player_height"
            android:src="@drawable/player_default"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#FFF"
            />
        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="@dimen/player_width"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/player_height"
            android:src="@drawable/player_default"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#FFF"
            />
        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="@dimen/player_width"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/player_height"
            android:src="@drawable/player_default"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#FFF"
            />


    </LinearLayout>



    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="@dimen/player_width"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/player_height"
        android:src="@drawable/player_default"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#FFF"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        />





</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add another `LinearLayout` around those groups and some padding for `ImageView`.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context="com.example.abay.myeleven.MyTeamActivity">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/attacks"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#FFF"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:src="@drawable/player_default" />

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#FFF"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:src="@drawable/player_default" />

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#FFF"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:src="@drawable/player_default" />

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>


<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/midfields"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"

    >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#FFF"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:src="@drawable/player_default" />

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#FFF"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:src="@drawable/player_default" />

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#FFF"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:src="@drawable/player_default" />


    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/defenders"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"


    >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#FFF"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:src="@drawable/player_default" />

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#FFF"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:src="@drawable/player_default" />

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#FFF"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:src="@drawable/player_default" />

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#FFF"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:src="@drawable/player_default" />

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>


<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
    android:background="#FFF"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp"
    android:src="@drawable/player_default" />


</LinearLayout>
```